# html dropdown text color change on selection

Tags: html

I have a html dropdown with different color text

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option style="color: Black" value="Black">Black</option>
  <option style="color: Blue" value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option style="color: Red" value="Red">Red</option>
  <option style="color: Orange" value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option style="color: Brown" value="Brown">Brown</option>
  <option style="color: Green" value="Green">Green</option>
  <option style="color: Purple" value="Purple">Purple</option>
  <option style="color: Cyan" value="Cyan">Cyan</option>
  <option style="color: Magenta" value="Magenta">Magenta</option>
</select>
```

Now You can all options are showing different colors but when I select any option selected value color has no color.. its default text color.

I want to keep same color

JSFiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/mahajan344/ztxws0n7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your HTML is stating only to style the `option` elements, not the overall `select`. Some browsers might automatically interpret this for you, but without it you cannot get this to work with just styling.

It can be overcome by some simple javascript which applies the selected option's style attribute on change of the select.

Below example uses jQuery:

```
$(function(){

$("select").change(function(){
    var $selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
    $(this).removeAttr("style").attr("style", $selectedOption.attr("style"));
});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ztxws0n7/2/

Comment: I find it strange how similar the *other* answer is to yours, they seem to have the same 'lack of indent' within the function. They also remove the style before setting the new one, which I don't believe is a very common technique at all... at least they changed some variable names :/

Comment: @musefan Haha I hadn't spotted that. Clearly this has become a new coding convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once you can find selected option style and remove previous styles in script then its works fine

```js
$(function(){

$("#selectbox").change(function(){
    var $yourchoice = $('#selectbox').find("option:selected");
    $(this).removeAttr("style").attr("style", $yourchoice.attr("style"));
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="selectbox">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option style="color: Black" value="Black">Black</option>
  <option style="color: Blue" value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option style="color: Red" value="Red">Red</option>
  <option style="color: Orange" value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option style="color: Brown" value="Brown">Brown</option>
  <option style="color: Green" value="Green">Green</option>
  <option style="color: Purple" value="Purple">Purple</option>
  <option style="color: Cyan" value="Cyan">Cyan</option>
  <option style="color: Magenta" value="Magenta">Magenta</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm just going to say this as bluntly as possible... did you copy the accepted answer?